# normalizing test sample for supervised models?

Tags: r, supervised-learning

have a few questions about normalizing training and test data.

As far as I understand it, for certain models (like k-NN) its imperative that you normalize the training sample because similarity is based on distance and if certain explanatory variables have much higher scales than others, it will disproportionally affect the similarity measurements.

So far, while I have read some competing arguments, it seems like overall one should standardize/normalize training sets before building models.

However, I am curious if one also does this with testing data, the arguments I have read is that you can't normalize "future data" you don't know, and if you normalize the dataset before you split you are leaking "future information" into your training sample which will affect the integrity of your model.

I have tried to read what literature is out there, but have still not found an answer I fully understand, though the above make some intuitive sense.

I know it is never “that simple” but I am looking for an generalization to some degree.
What approach should I use for my supervised models? 
1. Normalize then split into training and testing samples?
2. Split first then normalize each sample?
3. Split and only normalize the training sample and after test for accuracy on a non-normalized testing set?

Or will it vary substantially between models?

Thanks!

Comment: This may also be an appropriate question for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) , as it is more statistical in nature than program-oriented. I happen to think it's a great question.